# Как исключить пакеты из установки setuptools при extra_requires?

Tags: python, pip, setup

Есть такой код для установки приложения

```
from setuptools import setup


extras_require = {
    "strict": ["strictyaml"], 
}

setup(
    name="app",
    version="1.0",
    install_requires=[
        'PyYAML',
        'pandas==0.23.3',
        'numpy>=1.14.5',
        'matplotlib>=2.2.0',
        'jupyter'
    ],
    extras_require=extras_require,
)
```

Мне требуется реализовать следующий функционал:

Когда пользователь использует `pip install app` - устанавливается весь список библиотек из `install_requires`, но когда он использует экстра-аргумент `pip install app[strict]` - нужно, чтобы вместо `PyYAML` устанавливался `strictyaml`, а сам `PyYAML` не устанавливался, чтобы не загромождать список установленных библиотек.

При использовании кода выше при передаче `[strict]` установится `strictyaml`, но вместе с ним так же и `PyYAML`, что можно сделать, чтобы исключить пакет из установки?